# Append 2 pandas dataframes with subset of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04"],
                   "A": [1., 2., 3., 4.],
                   "B": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df_new = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-06"],
                       "A": [2, 3.5, 4, 5., 6.],
                       "B": ["b", "c1", "d", "e", "f"]})
df_new["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_new["date"])
```

So, my dataframes look like this

```
df
-----------------------
date            A    B
2019-01-01      1    a
2019-01-02      2    b
2019-01-03      3    c
2019-01-04      4    d

df_new
----------------------
date            A    B
2019-01-02      2    b
2019-01-03      3.5  c1
2019-01-04      4    d
2019-01-05      5    e
2019-01-06      6    f
```

From these dataframes, I would like to append df to df_new with specific condition as follows:

1. Any row with date available in both dataframe, we take such rows in df_new
2. Any row with date available in df but not in df_new, we take such rows in df

Finally my expected output look like this

```
Expected output
----------------------
date            A    B
2019-01-01      1    a      (take from df)
2019-01-02      2    b      (take from df_new)
2019-01-03      3.5  c1     (take from df_new)
2019-01-04      4    d      (take from df_new)
2019-01-05      5    e      (take from df_new)
2019-01-06      6    f      (take from df_new)
```

I can think of finding the row difference between 2 dataframes but it does not work when I take the date column into account.  May I have your suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and remove duplicates by `date` column by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), last create default uniqe index values by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) :

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_new]).drop_duplicates('date', keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
        date    A   B
0 2019-01-01  1.0   a
1 2019-01-02  2.0   b
2 2019-01-03  3.5  c1
3 2019-01-04  4.0   d
4 2019-01-05  5.0   e
5 2019-01-06  6.0   f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `outer` and then use `drop_duplicates` to remove duplicate rows.

```
df1 = df_new.merge(df, how='outer', on=['date','A','B']).sort_values(by='date').drop_duplicates('date').reset_index(drop=True)

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B       date                                                                                                                 
0  1.0   a 2019-01-01                                                                                                                 
1  2.0   b 2019-01-02                                                                                                                 
2  3.5  c1 2019-01-03                                                                                                                 
3  4.0   d 2019-01-04                                                                                                                 
4  5.0   e 2019-01-05                                                                                                                 
5  6.0   f 2019-01-06
```